# Run two different Rails application on one dedicated server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, dedicated-server

I have one dedicated server with below configurations

```
i3 - Dual Core - 3.06Ghz H/T
16GB RAM
500GB SATA2
```

Now I want to execute two different Rails application on one dedicated server. A both application are different but they are using common database.

Is it possible to do that? If yes – How can I do that? 
Is Phusion Passenger with Apache a good approach? If yes - How can I configure two application with one Phusion Passenger server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will describe how I run multiple Rails applications on one Linux server, using Apache, Phusion Passenger, and some version of Ruby.  You have many choices, but this should help you get started.  Many of these details come from the installation script

First, install Phusion Passenger.

```
> gem install passenger
```

Second, build the Apache 2 Passenger module.  You should be able to execute the following script installed during step one.

```
> passenger-install-apache2-module
```

This script will compile the Apache 2 module and explain how to configure Apache.  If dependencies are missing the script should offer some helpful advice about how to install them.

Third, edit your Apache configuration file.  I have to add something like this.  (Just use this for references and don't worry about .rvm)  The script run in step two will give you something that you can copy and paste.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ree/gems/passenger-3.0.9
PassengerRuby /Users/me/.rvm/wrappers/ree/ruby
```

Fourth, add something like this to your Apache configuration file *for each application* you want to run.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName app1.example.com
  DocumentRoot /somewhere/app1/public    # <-- be sure to point to 'public'!
  <Directory /somewhere/app1/public>
     AllowOverride all              # <-- relax Apache security settings
     Options -MultiViews            # <-- MultiViews must be turned off
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you have two Rails application sharing one database then they will both have similar connection information in config/database.yml

Comment: Can I load different versions of `passenger_module` with Apache2 at the same time? Because I have two rails apps with different ruby versions (and gemsets)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's definitely possible. I've never done it with Passenger + Apache, but I'm sure thats a fine way. I've only ever done it with thin + nginx.

Comment: Can I have some more details? any links? or any thing that I can start thinking or may be deploy the application.

Answer (score 0):

Passenger Phusion with Apache is a solid approach. The fact that they are using the same database shouldn't be a problem (just make sure they don't step on each other in any way).

Generally, just set things up as normal, but take a look at Apache name-based virtual hosts:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html